# set sprite on top layer in scene

Tags: android, andengine

I have two sprites here easyEnemy & bullDozer.  easyEnemy spawning in every seconds .A bulldozer comes in a random time.

I set bulldozer Zindex = 10 &  for easyEnemy I set nothing.

I want to show the bulldozer above all easyEnemy. But it not works.I call sortChildren() before calling the bulldozer on the scene. But it makes no sense.

```
public class Bulldozer extends PixelPerfectAnimatedSprite {

public Bulldozer(float pX, float pY,
        PixelPerfectTiledTextureRegion pTiledTextureRegion,
        VertexBufferObjectManager pVertexBufferObjectManager) {
    super(pX, pY, pTiledTextureRegion, pVertexBufferObjectManager);

    // SET z-INDEX FOR THIS
    setZIndex(20);
}  
}
```

In GameScene I call both easyEnemy and bullDozer. Firstly call easyEnemy then bullDozer.

**Edited: Add Code**

```
class GameScene extends Scene{
GameScene(){
// constructor 
createEasyEnemy();

CreateBullDOzer();

sortChildren();

}
public synchronized void createEasyEnemy(final float attackDuration,
            final float minTime, final float maxTime) {

        try {

            float delayTimer = attackDuration;
            aTimerHandler = new TimerHandler(delayTimer, true,
                    new ITimerCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onTimePassed(TimerHandler pTimerHandler) {
                            //
                            isEasyEnemyCreated = true;
                            engine.unregisterUpdateHandler(pTimerHandler);

                            final EasyEnemy aEasyEnemy = aEasyEnemyPoolObj
                                    .obtainPoolItem();
                            if (!aEasyEnemy.hasParent()) {
                                attachChild(aEasyEnemy);
                            }
                            aEasyEnemy.init(minTime, maxTime);
                            registerTouchArea(aEasyEnemy);
                            easyEnemyLinkedList.add(aEasyEnemy);
                        }
                    });

            registerUpdateHandler(aTimerHandler);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("--CreateEasyEnemy-Error", "" + e);
        }
    }


}
```

How I can achieve this?

Comment: you probably need to sort AFTER adding the dozer

Comment: i call sortChildren() after calling bullDozer. But got no change@jmr499485

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use layer concepts.This will meet your need and its really simple..
You need to add entity as layer and add spries to any layer you want
Here is a simple example

```
final int FIRST_LAYER = 0;
final int SECOND_LAYER = 1;

private void createLayers()
{
    scene.attachChild(new Entity()); // First Layer
    scene.attachChild(new Entity()); // Second Layer
}
```

Now you have two layers in scene and add sprite to any layer you like

```
scene.getChildByIndex(FIRST_LAYER).attachChild(yourEntity);
```

[This one is a useful link](http://www.matim-dev.com/using-entities-as-a-layers.html),
One more thing
Remember that  you need to add layers as the very first entities  in your scene

Comment: It works fine for the first time. But when I restart the game, I can't saw easyEnemy. But bullDozer comes as usual. In the Log cat it shows that easyEnemy Come@Renjith K N

Comment: what about the x ,y positions of easyEnemy?

Comment: First time easyEnemy moves & generates randomly as well. No problem there. Bulldozer places on top of easyEnemy.But I can't saw the easyEnemy after restart..Though Bulldozer comes as well!@Renjith

Comment: when restart I can see x & y of easyEnemy after passing the bulldozer on the scene. That means,when bulldozer comes on the scene, easy enemy can't come or can't see! also My co-ordinate have been changed. Both sprite comes middle of the scene. wanna chat with you. Thanks for support me@Renjith

Comment: hmm... when you add a child to a parent the childs co-ordinate is depends on the parents,means if you added the first layer at 5,5 position of scene and added a child to first layer with position 0,0 it will appear on the 5,5 of scene...May be thats the issue....

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29167/discussion-between-shihab-returns-and-renjith-k-n)

Comment: Do it got solved?,I saw your new question, will have a look on your code, Sry for not get in chat,I am in some office work that time, hopes let the problem get solved..